# How do I onSelect dropbox list value to display text label dynamically in Microsoft Excel using Powerapp?

Tags: excel, powerapps

Please help me look at the below advanced excel functions, I would like to onSelect the dropdown list value and display a text value on the label, named DisplayBuilding.

```
If(InspectorDropdown.Selected.Value = "Jonathan Soh", DisplayBuilding = Building.buildingID = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming DisplayBuilding is from a table, you would want to use "LookUp" function to find the record to display. Here is an example. When the selected value of Dropdown is "ccc", the "LookUp" function is evaulated to find a record which Titile equals to "bbb" and display its Title or any column of your choice.

```
If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "ccc", LookUp('aaaTable', Title = "bbb", Title))
```